# Return large data from WCF Service to ASP.NET Web Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

So we have console-hosted WCF Service and ASP.NET WEB Service (on IIS).
After some tough operation WCF Service must return some (large) data to ASP.NET Web Service for next processing. I tested on small results and everything is ok.
But after testing on real data that is a serialized result object that is near 4.5 MB, an error occurs on ASP.NET Web Service, which is the client in wcf-client-server communication.

This is the error I got:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '04:00:00'. Inner Exception: SocketException:"An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" ErrorCode = 10054

Messages size are configured by next binding (on server and client):

```
NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
netTcpBinding.TransactionFlow = true;
netTcpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 4,0, 0);
netTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
netTcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
netTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
netTcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 0;
netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;
```

`MaxObjectsInGraph` property is configured in a config file.

What can you advise me? And also I need example how programmatically set `MaxObjectsInGraph` property on client and server.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed by setting programmatically MaxObjectsInGraph(for serializer) as a service attribute.